# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized (SharePoint Online & C# Application)

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, authentication, asp.net

I am trying to insert items in SharePoint online list from c# console application using CSOM method, but every time it gives me only one error:

> "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

My question would be how can I authenticate to SharePoint online list from my C# console application?

I have checked my credentials, everything is correct still I am getting this unauthorized error.

Here is my code in c#:

[image: Insert item in SharePoint online list code]

Please do reply if anyone has any idea how to resolve this error!

Thanks,
Shaily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context you are creating is might create issue.

Whenever you are creating the context apply the credentials like below

```
context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
```

Post that go for creation/accessing list object or site objects.

Also:

Since you are getting 401 Authorization error, request you to verify the account and credentials you are creating have sufficient permission on the site and list.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gaurravs, I have tried using your code but still getting that same error, I think I should have checked my account permissions, could you give me the direction where I can find that type of permission on SharePoint online account which allows me to authenticate successfully?

Comment: open the siteurl in browser using same credentials, try to open and add a list item manually in the intended list. if it works. you have sufficient permissions then

Comment: Yes, I am able to add manually list items in SharePoint online list.

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this point? I have tried so many times its giving me just one error: 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: can you post your updated code? Is there any 2 factor authentication in your organization, also, are you trying to run the console application inside your office network only ?

Comment: string login = "UserName";  string password = "Password";   
var securePassword = new SecureString();
string siteUrl = "https://Comapny.sharepoint.com";
foreach (char c in password)securePassword.AppendChar(c);
try{ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login,securePassword);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();}
catch (Exception e){Console.WriteLine(e.Message);}
Console.ReadLine();

Comment: @Gaurrava - I have updated code on the previous comment, there is no 2-factor authentication in Our organization. I am running the console application from home not from the office network.

Answer (score 0):

Used below code :

It’s worth checking if you have site collection admin rights on the site. It’s a common misconception that if you have Global Admin rights or a SharePoint Online Admin role, You’ll automatically get admin access to SharePoint! You must add your account as a site collection administrator to each site.

```
string siteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"];
string clientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
using (ClientContext clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientID, clientSecret))
{
    List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("sDetails");
    clientContext.Load(oList);
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site);
    //clientContext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}

<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientId" value="XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <add key="SiteUrl" value="https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXXXX/" />       
  </appSettings>
```